Return owned value and reference to value
I have a Rust function, that has a fixed input type, but I can choose the return type:
fn foo(data: &[u8])

This function needs to make changes to that slice, so I created an owned value, so a Vec<u8>. I have to extract some parts of this vector into a library defined type, one which looks like this:
struct Foo<'a> {
    part1: &'a u8,
    part1: &'a u8,
    part1: &'a u8,
}

The struct does not have an owned type, and its internal types are all lifetimed. This struct can be created with a function that takes has his signature:
fn create(&'a [u8]) -> Foo<'a>

How can I return such a type? I can't just return it, as it references a local variable (the vector), which would be dropped at the end of the function. I also can't just return the both the vector and the Foo struct, as that would move the vector, and invalidate the reference to it.
If it is any help, the struct is a X509CertificationRequest from the crate x509_parser.
I have tried to convert the vector to a Pin<Box<Vec<u8>>> and borrow the data from that and return both of them, but that did not work. How would one do that?
I have read this, and this question, but I have found them to be unhelpful to my case, as they all suggest to rewrite the struct, which I cannot do.

Like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a7421784599436becd67946cd1391789.

@ChayimFriedman I think you missed the part where OP "needs to make changes to that slice"

Ah, then take &'a mut [u8].

An absolute last resort would be to leak a box, which might be okay if your program is only calling this function a few times.

@ChayimFriedman I am unable to modify the function's input type

You can use ouroboros to define a struct you can return which contains both the temporary vector and Foo:
#[ouroboros::self_referencing]
struct Return {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
    #[borrows(vec)]
    #[covariant]
    foo: Foo<'this>,
}

You can then use it similarly to this:
fn create<'a>(arr: &'a [u8]) -> Return {
    let mut inner = arr.to_vec();
    ReturnBuilder {
        vec: inner,
        foo_builder: |vec|{
            Foo {
                part1: &vec[0],
                part2: &vec[1],
                part3: &vec[2],
            }
        },
    }.build()
}

One of the answers to the questions you linked mentions this method, but I assume you overlooked that part of the answer.

I don't think this will work as it requires defining a new type. From the OP: "I have to extract some parts of this vector into a library defined type," so they don't have control over the definition of the type.

@cdhowie Depending on how the return value of create is used, this is maybe not a problem. foo with its original type Foo is still available inside the struct. The only thing OP explicitly mentioned was that they couldn't change the struct itself, I haven't done that.

If that is the case then it would be far easier to change the function's signature to accept a &mut [u8] or &mut Vec<u8>. The wording in the OP's question strongly implies that they cannot control the input to the function nor the shape of the returned struct. I guess we need OP to clarify.

While I cannot control the Foo struct itself, I am free to decide to return value of create, so this seems to work, when I've confirmed it, I'll mark it as answered.
@cdhowie Unfortunately, I cannot change the function to take a mutable reference, because the function that calls this function is a library function that only supplies a non-mutable reference.

I guess I will revert my edit then :)
